# How can i slide a form in another page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to slide a form with some contents in my main page on a button click.
I am using as asp.net razor pages.

Here is my Scenario. when i click on the highlighted button

[image]

One div with form should slide from right side of the page. The form will allow users to add their comments and the div will have previous comments added.

This is the Code for Button Click

```
<button type="button" title="Comments" id="RequestFormChatBox" data-id="100" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                        <i class="far fa-comment" style="color:white;"></i>
                    </button>
```

Here is the RequestFormChatBox Page

```
<div class="user-info">
    <div class="user-info-in">
        <div class="cc">Close</div>
        Comments
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>User 1</b>
                <p>This is for testing</p>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>User 2</b>
                <p>This is for testing</p>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>User 2</b>
                <p>This is for testing</p>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>User 2</b>
                <p>This is for testing</p>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>User 2</b>
                <p>This is for testing</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
            <textarea>Please Enter Your Comments</textarea>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to slide this page(div) in a ajax call. So that when each time user adds comments,it will be displayed.

This is my Ajax Code.But when click on the button the div is showing completely breaking the design instead of sliding from right side of page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/RequestFormChatBox',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#RequestFormChatBox").click(function () {
            $("#RequestFormChatBox").html(result);
            //$(".user-info").fadeIn().find(".user-info-in").animate({ "right": 0 }, 200);
        });
       //$("#RequestFormChatBox").html(result);
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#RequestFormChatBox").html(result);` will load the ChatBox Page into the Button. That doesn't make sense...

Try something like this:

```
$("#RequestFormChatBox").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/RequestFormChatBox',
        success: function (result) {
            $("body").append(result);
        }
    });
});
```

You also can load it with .html() in a preloaded container.

Comment: Hi @Alex, Thanks for the response. I tried your code, the result is appending to the body. I want the result to slide out from right side of the page. I tried fadein() option,but its just just sliding down and its taking entire page width. Is there any option to slide out from right?

Comment: @Teena, I know .slideUp() and .slideDown in jquery but no command to slide sidewards. Maybe you should have a look at .animate().
And yes, my code appends it to the body. You also can use a prepared container to load it into. You also need to apply some css to put it at the right place...